# ZF2 + DoctrineODM + doctrine-mongo-odm-module paginator tutorial

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

I have app on **ZF2 + DoctrineODM + doctrine-mongo-odm-module** and I can't find examples how to create pagination with these modules. Is there any example to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have a look here [Doctrine + ZF2 tips: Pagination](http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/doctrine-plus-zf2-tips-pagination)
it uses Doctrine ORM, but it should be very similar to Doctrine ODM.

Just use DoctrineMongoODMModule and [it's paginator](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Paginator/Adapter/DoctrinePaginator.php)